# Emoji Story - bad jokes edition

Tags: visual, rebus, emoji

For devices that cannot display all the emoji, Android screenshots are included with each.

1. > ✊✊❓❓

[image: joke 1]

2. > ❓☠️

[image: joke 2]

3. > ‍♂️‍♂️

[image: joke 3]

4. > ❓6️⃣7️⃣7️⃣9️⃣

[image: joke 4]

5. > ❓

[image: joke 5]

6. > ❓❌

[image: joke 6]

Comment: These were all horribly bad but #5 was the worst! :)

Comment: Your android screenshots seem to be missing some emoji, e.g. #3.

Comment: @Willtech Treat the bigger Android screenshots as the correct/intended version. If on #3 on your device, it shows a figure walking followed by a male symbol (this is how my Mac shows it), then that's just the device's quirky over-literal way of representing a "Man walking" emoji. Try to select it and you'll see that both the person and the symbol are part of one emoji.

Comment: @user568458 I can see them here ‍♂️‍♂️ not [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbFdt.jpg).

Comment: @user568458 It's strange that the ♂️ is missing on the 3rd guy.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. ✊✊❓❓

> Knock knock. Who's there? Boo. Boo who? You don't have to cry about it.

2. ❓☠️

> How much does a pirate pay for corn? A buccaneer.

3. ‍♂️‍♂️

> Two men walk into a bar. The 3rd man ducks.

4. ❓6️⃣7️⃣7️⃣9️⃣

> Why was 6 afraid of 7? Because 7 ate 9.

5. ❓

> Why can't your nose be 12 inches? Because then it'd be a foot. (Thanks to [@AustinWeaver](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41564/austin-weaver))

6. ❓❌

> What do you get when you cross a cat and a parrot? A carrot.

Comment: 5: rot13(jul pna'g lbhe abfr or 12 vapurf? gura vg'q or n sbbg)

Comment: oh that's the worst one yet, @AustinWeaver