# Idioms, Idioms, and wait..... More Idioms!

Tags: rebus

> **For this puzzle you have to find the English idiom in the rebus puzzles. I was inspired by this cool one about jokes, [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/63125/emoji-story-bad-jokes-edition)!**

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. Measure twice and cut once.

> 2. Not rocket science.

> 3. A bird in the hand is worth two in the bush.

> 4. Cost an arm and a leg.

> 5. Break the ice.

> 6. Out of the frying pan and into the fire.

> 7. (He's) not playing with a full deck.

Comment: Oh wow, I thought at least one of these would be hard ^-^. Good job you got them all!